# tensorflow py_func is handy but makes my training step very slow.

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have some efficiency issue using the tensorflow function py_func.

**Context**

In my project, I have a batch of tensor `input_features` of size `[? max_items m]`. The first dimension is set to `?` because it is a dynamic shape (the batch is read for a custom tensorflow reader, and shuffled using tf.train.shuffle_batch_join()). The second dimension correspond to an upper bound (the maximum number of items I can take for my example), the third dimension corresponds to the feature dimension space. I also have a tensor `num_items` that has dimension of batch size (so the shape is `(?,)`), indicating the number of items in the example, other are set to 0 (in a numpy writing style `input_feature[k, num_items[k]:, :] = 0`)

**Issue**

My workflow need some custom python operations (especially for dealing with indexing, I need or instance to perform clustering operations on some chunk of examples) and I use a few numpy function wrapped in `py_func` function. This works well, but training becomes very very slow (around 50 times slower than a model without this py_func), and the function itself is not time consuming.

**Questions**

1 - Is this computing time increase normal? The function wrapped in `py_func` gives me a new tensor that is multiplied further in the process. Does it explain the computing time? (I mean gradient may be more difficult to compute with such function).

2 - I'm trying to modify my processing and avoid using `py_func` function. However, it was very handy for extracting data with numpy indexing (especially with my data formatting), and I have some difficulties to pass it in a TF way. For instance, if I have a tensor `t1` with shape`[-1, n_max, m]` (first dimension is batch_size which is dynamic) and `t2` with shape `[-1,2]` containing integers. Is there an easy way to perform mean operation in tensorflow that will results in `t_mean_chunk` with shape `(-1, m)` where (in a numpy formulation) :
`t_mean_chunk[i,:] = np.mean(t1[i, t2[i,0]:t2[i,1], :], axis=0)` ?
This was (among others operations) the kind of things I was doing in wrapped function.

Comment: Assuming `pyfunc` operates much like the `np.vectorize`, I'm not surprised that it slows things down.  `tensorflow` uses a lot of its own compiled code.  But with this Python function in the mix, it has to resort to some sort of interpreted iteration.  That is much slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1 is hard to answer without the exact py_func, but as hpaulj mentioned in his comment, it's not too surprising that it's slowing things down. As a worst-case fallback, `tf.scan` or `tf.while_loop` with a `TensorArray` may be somewhat faster. However, the best case is to have a vectorized solution with TensorFlow ops, which I think is possible in this case.

As for question 2, I'm not sure if it counts as easy, but here's a function which computes your indexing expression:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def range_mean(index_ranges, values):
  """Take the mean of `values` along ranges specified by `index_ranges`.

  return[i, ...] = tf.reduce_mean(
    values[i, index_ranges[i, 0]:index_ranges[i, 1], ...], axis=0)

  Args:
    index_ranges: An integer Tensor with shape [N x 2]
    values: A Tensor with shape [N x M x ...].
  Returns:
    A Tensor with shape [N x ...] containing the means of `values` having
    indices in the ranges specified.
  """
  m_indices = tf.range(tf.shape(values)[1])[None]
  # Determine which parts of `values` will be in the result
  selected = tf.logical_and(tf.greater_equal(m_indices, index_ranges[:, :1]),
                            tf.less(m_indices, index_ranges[:, 1:]))
  n_indices = tf.tile(tf.range(tf.shape(values)[0])[..., None],
                      [1, tf.shape(values)[1]])
  segments = tf.where(selected, n_indices + 1, tf.zeros_like(n_indices))
  # Throw out segment 0, since that's our "not included" segment
  segment_sums = tf.unsorted_segment_sum(
      data=values,
      segment_ids=segments, 
      num_segments=tf.shape(values)[0] + 1)[1:]
  divisor = tf.cast(index_ranges[:, 1] - index_ranges[:, 0],
                    dtype=values.dtype)
  # Pad the shape of `divisor` so that it broadcasts against `segment_sums`.
  divisor_shape_padded = tf.reshape(
      divisor,
      tf.concat([tf.shape(divisor), 
                 tf.ones([tf.rank(values) - 2], dtype=tf.int32)], axis=0))
  return segment_sums / divisor_shape_padded
```

Example usage:

```
index_range_tensor = tf.constant([[2, 4], [1, 6], [0, 3], [0, 9]])
values_tensor = tf.reshape(tf.range(4 * 10 * 5, dtype=tf.float32), [4, 10, 5])
with tf.Session():
  tf_result = range_mean(index_range_tensor, values_tensor).eval()
  index_range_np = index_range_tensor.eval()
  values_np = values_tensor.eval()

for i in range(values_np.shape[0]):
  print("Slice {}: ".format(i),
        tf_result[i],
        numpy.mean(values_np[i, index_range_np[i, 0]:index_range_np[i, 1], :],
                   axis=0))
```

Prints:

```
Slice 0:  [ 12.5  13.5  14.5  15.5  16.5] [ 12.5  13.5  14.5  15.5  16.5]
Slice 1:  [ 65.  66.  67.  68.  69.] [ 65.  66.  67.  68.  69.]
Slice 2:  [ 105.  106.  107.  108.  109.] [ 105.  106.  107.  108.  109.]
Slice 3:  [ 170.  171.  172.  173.  174.] [ 170.  171.  172.  173.  174.]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Your example is great and shows me exactly the kind of thing I wanted to do.