# Compute the mean for each tensor's row in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new in tensorflow and I want to compute the mean from each row from a tensor. Tensorflow has the tf.reduce_mean operation in order to do that. The problem is that when a row has a nan value the mean for this row is nan also. Except from that, I want to implement this on my own in order to understand better the philosophy tensorflow has. So how could I implement this manually? The code I wrote:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

ratings = np.array([[7, 6, 7, 4, 5, 4], [6, 7, np.NaN, 4, 3, 4], [np.NaN, 3, 3, 1, 1, np.NaN],
                   [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4], [1, np.NaN, 1, 2, 3, 3]], dtype = np.float16)

tRatings = tf.convert_to_tensor(ratings, dtype = np.float16)

means = tf.get_variable("means", shape=(5), dtype=tf.float16)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    mean = tf.reduce_mean(tRatings, axis=1)
    print(sess.run(mean))
```

Comment: There are two approaches: You can define the mean operation in numpy and use tf.py_func to call the numpy function. Alternatively, define it in tensorflow itself but replace NaNs with 0 as desired. You can use tRatings=tf.where(tf.is_nan(tRatings), tf.zeros_like(tRatings), tRatings) to replace NaNs with zeros.

Comment: If I replace the nan values with zeros then I will find a wrong mean. I want to compute the mean from the existing values from each row.

Comment: You can count nans with tf.is_nan. Then before dividing the sum, substract the number of nans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
ratings = np.array([[7, 6, 7, 4, 5, 4], [6, 7, np.NaN, 4, 3, 4], [np.NaN, 3, 3, 1, 1, np.NaN],
                       [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4], [1, np.NaN, 1, 2, 3, 3]], dtype = np.float16)

tRatings = tf.convert_to_tensor(ratings, dtype = np.float16)
means = tf.get_variable("means", shape=(5), dtype=tf.float16)
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  #mean = tf.reduce_mean(tRatings, axis=1)
  tRatings_wonan=tf.where(tf.is_nan(tRatings), tf.zeros_like(tRatings), tRatings)
  sum = tf.reduce_sum(tRatings_wonan,axis=1)
  count_nans = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.is_nan(tRatings), tf.float16),axis=1)
  mean = tf.div(sum,tf.subtract(tf.cast(tf.shape(tRatings)[1], tf.float16),count_nans))
  print(sess.run(mean))
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. If I use tf.py_func, do I lose much efficiency?

Comment: Depends on specific implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42927920/tensorflow-py-func-is-handy-but-makes-my-training-step-very-slow